# Crystal Reports Formula

Tags: crystal-reports

First, I'm a super beginner to Crystal

Next I'm attempting to write a formula that ultimately produces the 1st day in the month given a date range parameter, @1stofMonth

Currently @1stmonth is `minimum ({?DateRange})`

My thought was then `minimum (LastFullMonth) {@1stofMonth}`  Obviously not correct syntax

Example, if Date Range is 9/6 - 9/10

```
Step 1 = 9/6
Step 2 = 9/1
```

Thanks

Comment: The Date Range is defined in this format always? with a space between the first From date and the '-'??

Answer (score 0):

Well, to reach your destination you have to define two formulas:
`@FromDate` and `@1stofMonth`.

Assuming you are always sending your date range in this format, define the following formula in `@FromDate`: `Split ({?DateRange},' ')[1]`

Then the 2nd formula `@1stofMonth`: `Split( {@FromDate},'/')[1] + '/1'`